# has Google Analytics turned off the "Import Data" option? I have clicked the option many times but it didn't work

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I used a Google analytics demo account for exploring. I tried many times to import data, but it didn't work. when I clicked the "import data" option, it didn't show me anything.

[here screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nveE8.jpg)

Has Google turned off the "Import Data" option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exprerience similar issue from time to time and I just sign out and sign in again and then it works fine (it may sound trivial I know)